# Exit from loops when true

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I use the following code and I need to exit the loop when the condition is true,I try with every and some without success,any idea?

the *array* is given and I cannot change it,
currntly when condition is true the loop is still processing...

https://jsfiddle.net/z4oxsa1b/10/

```
 var json = {
  "prov": [
    {
      "save": {
        "pa": "aa",
        "func": "sa"

      },
      "delete": {
        "pa": "sof",
        "func": "delete"

      }
    }
  ]
};

var array = [];
array.push(json);

_.filter(array, function (config) {
    config['prov'].some(function (provider) {
        _.every(provider, function (config) {
            if (config.pa === 'aa') {
                //now need to exit
                console.log("true")
            }
        });
    });
});
```

UPDATE: the answers are not helping ,assume that I call to the filter loop inside method I want to **exit this** **method** when the if condition is true...

Comment: Can you explain with a sentence the goal of these loops please ?

Comment: You are not `filter`ing a list,  checking that `some`thing in a list passes a condition or checking that `every` item in a list passes a condition because you have no return statements in the predicates and are not attempting to use those return values. What is the intention of the code?

Comment: Answers DO help : you're thinking procedural and writing functional. So you'll have to either start thinking functional, or writing procedural, both of which I explicitely suggested. We can show you the water, but noone can force you to drink it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply exit the `_.every` function by using `return`.

```
_.every(provider, function (config) {
    if (config.pa === 'aa') {
        //now need to exit
        console.log("true")
        return; // --> just return
    }
});
```

Comment: Technically correct, but that doesn't help if (later down the road), he has some code after the loop the needs to be executed as well. Return exits the function right away.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your comment can you give an example? The question is how to break the iteration, `return` will do exactly that and continue from the line after the (`_.every`) loop. Not much different than using a `for` loop with `break`.

Comment: @StoyanDekov - thanks but it doesnt work after I return the loop is still running for the addinal values,I want to exit this loops ...assume I call the filter isnide method exit this method with boolean true

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. Using return will just have the predicate return undefined, which, for `every`'s purpose, is tantamount to a boolean false. Nothing to do with breaking loops !

Comment: I posted a proposition in an answer below, though not going all the way to writing the code for you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're not using loops, here. You're using higher order functions. `break`, `return` or `continue` will be of no help.

The idea of those higher-order functions is that you worry *less* about when they break a loop or not : that kind of worries falls onto the library function's implementation. As a matter of fact, that's exactly what this implementation does : https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L244-L255

So, rather than asking "how do I break the loop", I'd rather question if you're feeling confident about the **correctness** of the filter that you've expressed. Indeed it looks to me as if you may have one nesting level too-much in your chained functions here, yet I'm not feeling to sure about what you're trying to achieve, and thus I can't be assertive about that.

One more thing hinting for a need to read the functions' documentation is that the predicate inside `every` needs to return a value. For now yours returns `undefined` all the time. Similarly, Javascript does not by default return the value of a function's last expression. Therefore, `_.every` and `config.prov.some(...` should be preceded by a `return` instruction.

Another way out could be to actually use good'ol Javascript loops, trading conciseness for clarity if you're more comfortable with procedural style instead of functional style ; there you'll be able to use the built-ins. Labeled loops may help if you want to break an outer loop.

Comment: (edited to shift emphasis about the OP maybe missing the actual point, after I read the question once more)

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at the [Break and Continue](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp) statements in JavaScript.

```
_.filter(array, function (config) {
  config['prov'].some(function (provider) {
    _.every(provider, function (config) {
      if (config.pa === 'aa') {
        //now need to exit
        break; // exits the if statement
        console.log("true")
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this is just exit the if I want to exit the all loops ,assume I call the filter isnide method exit this method with boolean true

Comment: in addition when I put break as you mention I got error Illegal break statement

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Gunnar - none of the answer is working , do you have idea?

Comment: It's because nobody really gets what you're trying to do. I've revised my answer in this direction...

Answer (score -4):

Try the break command (just below the console.log("true"))

> break;

Comment: You can't use break in underscore looping methods